# Karma.config: sass tilde importer

Tags: angular, sass, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I set up an angular 6 project by angular-cli.

I installed `karma-scss-preprocessor` as dev dependency to load sass file in karma test.
Following karma.config:

```
...
config.set({
basePath: '',
browserNoActivityTimeout: 60000,
frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
plugins: [
  require('karma-jasmine'),
  require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
  require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
  require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
  require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
  require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
  require('karma-scss-preprocessor')
],
preprocessors: {
  'styles.scss': ['scss'],
},
files: [
  { pattern: 'styles.scss', watched: true,  included: true, served: true }
],
...
```

Now I get the error:

```
File to import not found or unreadable: ~@onepackage/onelib/scss/all.
```

due to tilde at the import of onepackage/lib in `styles.scss`.

I've tried to add `require('node-sass-tilde-importer')` in plugins section of karma.json, but it doesn't solve.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `require('node-sass-tilde-importer')` in `karma-scss-preprocessor` options

```
...
plugins: [
  require('karma-jasmine'),
  require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
  require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
  require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
  require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
  require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
  require('karma-scss-preprocessor')
],
scssPreprocessor: {
  options: {
    importer: require('node-sass-tilde-importer')
  }
},
...
```

Comment: It works! But it's odd, now with this config I get `Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing`, I have tried to increase `browserNoActivityTimeout` in karma.conf.js, but it seems it's a deprecated option.